# Google Maps Weather Layer on top of other

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-fusion-tables

I have a google map with two layers:

1 - Fusion Layer

2 - Weather Layer

The problem is, where fusion appears, the weather layer isn't visible anymore. So basically, I want like a css z-index property, to display the weather at the top

My code till now:

```
$(function() {
  window.table_id = "abc";

  window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.056091682584327, -96.01576748461912),
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  google.initializeWeather();
  return google.initializeFusion();
});

google.initializeFusion = function() {
  google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
  return window.fusionLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: window.map,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: "col2",
      from: "abc",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });
};

google.initializeWeather = function() {
  var cloudLayer, weatherLayer;

  weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
    map: window.map,
    temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
  });

  cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
  return cloudLayer.setMap(window.map);
};
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the weather layer after the Fusion Tables layer?

Comment: Yes, this was my first try, but no difference

Answer (score 0):

It's a headache that we get to deal with when using more than 1 styled fusiontables layer. What works 1 day may not work the next, and it seems to be on Google's end.

You can try to initialize one before the other, or clear both and bring one back (background) and then the other (foreground) but that seems to have its own issues.

It's an issue that the Fusion Tables and Maps staff at Google need to figure out, and unfortunately I've not seen a decent workaround to this point.